# What does it mean that 'lift is pretty much the same as map'?

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, lifting

Leonardo Borges has written an excellent post called ["Functional Composition With Monads, Kleislis and Functors"](http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2014/06/17/functional-composition-with-monads-kleisli-functors/).

In it he comments:

> Mark pointed out to me that lift is pretty much the same as map but with the arguments reversed.

This means that this:

```
val f = Functor[Option].lift(parts) compose make
```

can be refactored to:

```
val g = make(_:Int).map(parts)
```

My question is,**What does it mean that 'lift is pretty much the same as map?'**

Comment: I'd even rather say that `map` is just a flipped `lift`. Scala is the only language I know of that uses that order of arguments: Consider Python's `map`, Haskell's `fmap`, Lisp's `mapcar`... they're all in `lift`'s order. That probably comes from Scala's tendency to infix notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [scalaz functor code](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L20):

`def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]`

`def lift[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B] = map(_)(f)`

NOTE: lift is just defined in terms of map (reversing the arguments)

Mostly when people start with Functional programming they are introduced to `map` as mapping a function over a sequence of things, but `map` in general is a more abstract concept related to functor.